# Creating dataframe from pandas function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting some text analytics and writing code to show the occurrence of a word each month from a given dataset. I have the following function which outputs the frequency of the given word every month - however I am struggling to transform this into a dataframe (columns; month, word frequency).

Appreciate any help!

```
import collections

df=df.set_index(df['Date'])
for u,v in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")):
    words=sum(v['Processed'].str.split(' ').values.tolist(),[])
    c = collections.Counter(words)
    print (c['word'])
```

currently outputs:

```
0
1
0
1
1
2
1
18
6
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your collection into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

df=df.set_index(df['Date'])

results = []
for u,v in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")):
    words=sum(v['Processed'].str.split(' ').values.tolist(),[])
    c = collections.Counter(words)
    
    # convert counter to dataframe
    cdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c,orient='index',columns=['frequency']).reset_index()
    
    # add identifer to dataframe
    cdf['month'] = u 
    
    # collect results
    results += [cdf]

# concatenate results
results = pd.concat(results)
```